# List all dependents of a dependency from lock file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, pnpm

Is it possible to list all dependents of specific dependency from a lock file (npm/pnpm/***yarn***)?

- It's the opposite of `yarn ls`
- I prefer not to read the lock file if there is a built-in command in npm/pnpm/yarn

---

I know that I can ask npm registery for that but I'm looking for a solution without network calls (expect npm/pnpm/yarn install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pnpm and Yarn both have a `why` command. So you can run `<yarn|pnpm> why <pkg>`.

In the case of pnpm, `pnpm why <pkg>` does the same as `pnpm ls <pkg> --depth Infinity`. It is because pnpm creates a non-flat node_modules.

Output example of `pnpm why glob`:

```
@pnpm/registry-mock 1.8.0
├─┬ cpr 3.0.1
│ └─┬ rimraf 2.7.1
│   └── glob 7.1.5
├─┬ rimraf 3.0.0
│ └── glob 7.1.5
└─┬ verdaccio 4.3.4
  ├─┬ bunyan 1.8.12
  │ └─┬ mv 2.1.1
  │   └─┬ rimraf 2.4.5
  │     └── glob 6.0.4
  └─┬ mv 2.1.1
    └─┬ rimraf 2.4.5
      └── glob 6.0.4
tslint 5.20.0
└── glob 7.1.5
verdaccio 4.3.4
├─┬ bunyan 1.8.12
│ └─┬ mv 2.1.1
│   └─┬ rimraf 2.4.5
│     └── glob 6.0.4
└─┬ mv 2.1.1
  └─┬ rimraf 2.4.5
    └── glob 6.0.4
```

Comment: can I output it in a way that it will be easier to parse using node?

Comment: yes, a `--json` flag is supported. Type `<pnpm|yarn> help ls` for info about all the available options.